# Deleting various numbers of directories that remained still minimum 5 directories

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, delete-directory

I have next code, the delete still one last directories. And I need delete various number of directories, so that it remains still only 5 directories.

```
<delete verbose="true">
    <first count="1">
        <sort>
            <date/>
            <dirset dir="">
            </dirset>
        </sort>
    </first>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to delete all directories except for the latest 5? Mind that [`allbutlast`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#allbutlast)  is a relatively new feature of Ant (1.9.5).

```
<delete verbose="true">
    <allbutlast count="5">
        <sort>
            <date/>
            <dirset dir="">
            </dirset>
        </sort>
    </allbutlast>
</delete>
```